# How to create a modal instance inside an ajaxLink

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-modal, wicket

I'm using an AjaxLink to open a Modal.
This modal displays first a "Are you sure" panel and then a panel with the result of the operation together with a Close button.
I close the modal and if I open it again I get the second panel and not the first.
I would like everytime the modal is opened to get the sequence of panels from the beginning, i.e., starting with the initial panel.
I tried to instantiate the modal inside the AjaxLink but I have issues with the html markup.

HTML

```
 <wicket:panel>
    <div wicket:id="modal2"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" wicket:id="link"><span 
     wicket:id="buttonLabel"></span></button>
</wicket:panel>
```

Java

```
  public class ButtonPayment2 extends Panel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Label label;
    private List<String> current;
    private String party;
    private DetailsModal2 modal;
    private String guid;


    @SpringBean
    private Environment env;

    @SpringBean
    private IService service;

    public ButtonPayment2(String componentId, IModel<PaymentDomain> rowmodel, String invoiceId, String paymentId){

    super(componentId);

    current = service.getPById(rowmodel.getObject());
    guid = rowmodel.getObject().getPaymentGUID();
    initiateButton(current);


    modal = new DetailsModal2("modal2",rowmodel,party){
        @Override
        public void closeAction(AjaxRequestTarget target, boolean toPass) {
            super.closeAction(target, toPass);
        }
    };
    modal.header(Model.of("Transaction process"));
    modal.setHeaderVisible(true);
    modal.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(modal);

    add(new AjaxLink("link"){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) { 

            modal.show(target);     
            target.add(this);

      }//close onclick
   }.add(label));//close ajaxLink

    modal.detach();
 }
```

}

DetailsModal2.java

```
public class DetailsModal2 extends Modal<IModel<PaymentDomain>> {

@SpringBean
private IService service;

private String party;
private BootstrapAjaxLink<String> noButton;
private ResponseMessage message;
private String paymentId;
private ProcessingPanel panel2;
private Panel replacedPanel;
private boolean booleanToPass;
private IModel<PaymentDomain> model;


public DetailsModal2(String id, IModel<PaymentDomain> model, String party) {
    super(id);
    this.party = party;
    this.model = model;
    this.paymentId = model.getObject().getGUID();

    replacedPanel = new AreYouSure("replacedPanel");
    replacedPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(replacedPanel);

    panel2 = new ProcessingPanel("replacedPanel");

    addButton(new BootstrapAjaxLink<String>("button", null, Buttons.Type.Warning, new ResourceModel("details")) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

            addNewPanel(new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("replacedPanel") {
                @Override
                public Component getLazyLoadComponent(String markupId) {
                    if (!condition) {

                        message = service.getPayment(paymentId);

                        if (message == null) {
                            booleanToPass = true;
                            return new VotingResultPanel(markupId, true);
                        } else {
                            return new VotingResultPanel(markupId, false);
                        }
                    } // close if

                    else if (condition)) {

                        message = service.setPayment(paymentId);
                        if (message == null) {
                            booleanToPass = false;
                            return new VotingResultPanel(markupId, true);

                        } else {
                            System.out.println("" + message.getError());
                            return new VotingResultPanel(markupId, false);
                        }
                    }

                    else {
                        System.out.println("It was not possible to access the db");
                    }
                }
            }, target);

            this.setVisible(false);
            target.add(this);
            noButton.setLabel(Model.of("Close"));
            target.add(noButton);

            target.add(this);
        }

    });

    noButton = new BootstrapAjaxLink<String>("button", null, Buttons.Type.Primary) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target){
            closeAction(target,booleanToPass);
        }
    }.setLabel(Model.of("No"));
    addButton(noButton);

}

public void closeAction(AjaxRequestTarget target, boolean flag){
    close(target);

}

public void addNewPanel(Panel addpanel, AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    Panel newPanel = null;
    newPanel = addpanel;
    newPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    replacedPanel.replaceWith(newPanel);
    target.add(newPanel);
    replacedPanel = newPanel;
 }
}// close class
```

HTML of DetailsModal2

```
 <wicket:extend>    
     <div><span wicket:id="replacedPanel"> </span></div>
 </wicket:extend>
```

New solution for this particular case, DetailsModal2 changed:

```
 public class DetailsModal2 extends Modal<IModel<PaymentDomain>> {

 @SpringBean
 private IService service;

 private Component noButton;
 private Component yesButton;
 private Component noButton;
 private String paymentId;
 private Panel replacedPanel;
 private IModel<PaymentDomain> model;

 public DetailsModal2(String id, IModel<PaymentDomain> model, String party) 
 {
  super(id);
  this.party = party;
  this.model = model;
  this.paymentId = model.getObject().getPaymentGUID();

  replacedPanel = new AreYouSure("replacedPanel");
  replacedPanel = panel1;
  replacedPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
  add(replacedPanel);


  addButton(yesButton = new BootstrapAjaxLink<String>("button", null, Buttons.Type.Warning, new ResourceModel("details")) {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

        addNewPanel(new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("replacedPanel") {
            @Override
            public Component getLazyLoadComponent(String markupId) {
                if (!condition)) {

                    message = service.getPayment(paymentId);

                    if (message == null) {
                        return new VotingResultPanel(markupId, true);
                    } else 
                    {
                        return new VotingResultPanel(markupId, false);
                    }
                } // close if

                else if (condition)) {

                    message = service.setPayment(paymentId);
                    if (message == null) {
                        return new VotingResultPanel(markupId, true);

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("" + message.getError());
                        return new VotingResultPanel(markupId, false);
                    }
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }
        }, target);

        this.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
        noButton.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        noButton.setVisible(false);
        closeButton.setVisible(true);
        target.add(this, noButton, closeButton);
    }

  });

  noButton = new BootstrapAjaxLink<String>("button", null, Buttons.Type.Primary) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target){
        close(target);
    }
}.setLabel(Model.of("No"));
addButton(noButton);

}

 closeButton = new BootstrapAjaxLink<String>("button", null, Buttons.Type.Primary) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target){
            addNewPanel(panel1,target);
            yesButton.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            yesButton.setVisible(true);
            noButton.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            noButton.setVisible(true);
            closeButton.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            closeButton.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
            closeButton.setVisible(false);
            target.add(yesButton,noButton,closeButton);
            close(target);

        }
    }.setLabel(Model.of("Close"));
    closeButton.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
    closeButton.setVisible(false);
    addButton(closeButton);
}


 public void addNewPanel(Panel addpanel, AjaxRequestTarget target) {
  Panel newPanel = null;
  newPanel = addpanel;
  newPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
  replacedPanel.replaceWith(newPanel);
  target.add(newPanel);
  replacedPanel = newPanel;
 }
}// close class
```

Comment: Hi.

You should show also code for DetailsModal2 where (I guess) you decide which panel to show in the modal.

Comment: The usual way would be to use the ModalWindow method `setContent` inside your onClick method. But since you seem to have written your own ModalWIndow (Sub)class you need to show us the code of that class as well as Andrea pointed out.

Comment: Hi, I added  the code of DetailsModal2, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to move the following lines

```
replacedPanel = new AreYouSure("replacedPanel");
replacedPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
add(replacedPanel);
```

to onConfigure and change add() to addOrReplace()

Comment: Hi, thanks Andrea and Oh God Spiders for the interest.
At this moment I was able to do it  and i put the new version of DetailsModal2 class up.
Briefly description, all my buttons are in the footer of the modal and initially I only had two, the yes and the second (no and close, here only the label was changed).
So I added a third button the close button and played with the visibility of the three buttons.
Also the onclick method of the close button was override to call again the method addNewPanel('reference for the first panel', ajaxtarget).
So when we close we change again the panels.